# Can I create webserver localhost HTTPS vis Grizzly

Tags: https, localhost, grizzly

I need to test some thing on HTTPS protocol webserver by using Grizzly.
Can I do that?

For more specific:
Can I request this:

```
https://localhost/mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/blob/2.3.x/samples/websockets/chat-ssl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/samples/websockets/ChatWebSocketSecuredServer.java)

Ignore the WebSocket related stuff.  Pay attention to lines 74,75, and the method at line 99.